# AngularJS вызов модального окна на той же странице

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пишу свой первый проект на AngularJS, но столкнулся с трудностью ,открытия модального окна на странице.
Вот настройки перехода между страниц:

```
csApp.config([
 '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvide, $locationProvider){
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
      });
    $routeProvide
        .when('/',{
          templateUrl:'template/index.html',
          controller:'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/modal/:name',{
            controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
  }
]);
```

И пустой контроллер:

```
csApp.controller('ModalCtrl',[
    '$scope','$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
        console.log('modal');
    }
]);
```

Хочу сделать что бы при нажатии на ссылку открывалась модальное окно, на это же странице (которая уже открыта), с контентом из `template/modal/:name.tpl` ,но не знаю как это сделать.
Облазил кучу страниц, но не как не могу понять как это можно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы открыть модальное окно не обьязательно (не нужно) поменять *route*. Поэтому убираем вот следующий код:

```
.when('/modal/:name',{
     controller: 'ModalCtrl'
})
```

По сути вам нужно одну ссылку, которую при нажатии вызывает функцию для открытия модального окна. Типо того:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="openModal(name)">Открыть окно</button>
```

Вам нужно модуль для модальных окон. Берём например [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). 
В *index.html* добавить:

- bootstrap.css
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js (ui-bootstrap с темплетамы)

В декларации приложения добавить модуль `'ui.bootstrap'`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

В контроллере, внедрить `$uibModal` и декларировать функцию для открытия окна:

```
$scope.openModal = function (name) {
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'template/modal/' + name + '.tpl',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl'
    }
};
```

Остаётся написать `ModalCtrl` в зависимости от того, что будет в вашем окне.

Comment: А нету модуля который бы работал отдельно, без bootstrap ?

Comment: Есть, например [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog).

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.